# How to start more than one animation with unity animator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have an animatormanager able to create run time animation from 1 animation (start frame, end frame and delay then the speed is calculated, will do morphing and more later). My unity version is **5.3.1f1**

Everything work fine, some stuff are not done but are optional. The animator can queue requested animation to prevent interupting the current one.

The thing is, I can only start 1 time an animation with an object. The code to launch the next animation is exactly the same but there is just nothing to do.

Event if its 2 time the same animation with the same animation data
All formula are good and tested.

I did intensive debugging with breakpoint to make sure everything is fine at any point

Is there something to prevent me from starting an animation 2 time on an object one after an other?. I have no error or warning at all. The first animation work fine no matter the settings I put in my AnimData struct, but the second time, nothing happen.

Here is the essential:

```
public int? startAnim(int index)
{
    if(index < animIndex.Count)
    {
        startAnim(animIndex[index]);
    }
    return null;
}

//private because the struct is internal, this make sure the animator keep control of the list.
private int? startAnim(AnimData animD)
{
    if(locked)
    {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        Debug.Log("anim locked");
        #endif

        return null;
    }

    //current anim (queue anim) not finished
    if(endTime > Time.time)
    {
        if(canQueue)
        {
            addToQueue(animD);
            return animDataQ.Count;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        endTime = Time.time + animD.TotalTime;
        StartCoroutine(animManager(animD));
        return 0;
    }

    return null;
}

#endregion anim starters

private IEnumerator animManager(AnimData animData)
{
        animator.speed = Mathf.Abs(animData.calculateSpeed(animLength, AnimType.main, currentKey).Value);

        //animator.Play(0,0, animData.StartKey/animLength);
        if(animData.AnimSpeed > 0)
        {
            animator.Play(0,0, animData.StartKey/animLength/2);
        }
        else
        {
            //animator.Play(0,0, (animLength * 2) - (animData.StartKey/animLength));
            animator.Play(0,0, (((animLength*2) - animData.StartKey)/(animLength * 2)));
        }

            //animator.Play(0,0, (animData.AnimSpeed > 0) ?  animData.StartKey/animLength : ((animLength * 2) - (animData.StartKey/animLength)));

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(animData.Delay);
        animator.Stop();

        yield return null;

    endAnim();

}


private void addToQueue(AnimData animD)
{
    animDataQ.Enqueue(animD);
    endTime += animD.TotalTime;
    queueTime += animD.TotalTime;
}

private void endAnim()
{
    if(canQueue && animDataQ.Count > 0)
    {
        StartCoroutine(animManager(animDataQ.Dequeue()));
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a work around.
I dont want to mark it as an accepted solution since its not "clean" in my opinion

there is certainly some kind of problem with the animator for some specific case like mine.

my solution was to use animator.speed = 0 instead of animator.stop();
everything worked instantly with that small change

i will ask my question to the unity forum because there is something strange for sure